# SSH "no such file or directory" error on git push

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have a private key that lives at `~/.ssh/github_rsa`, and the corresponding public key has been uploaded to my Github account. I created a repository and set it up as the remote for the directory I'm working from, and in that directory's `.git` folder, I have the following `config` file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    sshCommand = 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/github_rsa -o IdentitiesOnly=yes'
[remote "repoName"]
    url= git@github.com:myusername/repoName.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/repoName/*
```

When I run `git push -u repoName main`, I get the following error:

```
'ssh -i ~/.ssh/github_rsa -o IdentitiesOnly=yes': line 1: ssh -i github_rsa -o IdentitiesOnly=yes: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Removing `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` has no effect. Changing permissions on the key from 600 to 400 also had no effect. The file definitely exists, and exists at exactly that path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gitconfig doesn't recognize single quotes. Use double quotes.

```
[core]
    sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/github_rsa -o IdentitiesOnly=yes"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. For whatever reason, every example I found online of this uses single quotes, but this fixed the issue.

Comment: @user242007: probably those examples are written for people using sh/bash to run `git config` to *set* these, with the expectation that the config file will end up with no quotes at all in it (which is also OK here). As it was, you convinced Git to attempt to run a command named `ssh -i ~/.ssh/...` (all one big word), rather than to run a command `ssh` with arguments `-i`, the path to the identity file, and so on.

Comment: It's also more typical to use the ssh configuration itself to set up the identity or identities you wish to deliver to particular hosts, rather than using the `-i` and `-o` options in the command line, since this then works with other ssh commands (you can then run `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to test, without needing `-i` and `-o` options).